# DbUp throwing Npgsql exception when using SQL-language syntax for PostgreSQL functions

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, dbup

I'm using DbUp to deploy to a PostgreSQL-14 database. When I try to create a function or procedure using SQL-language syntax, DbUp throws an Npgsql.PostgresException 42601, claiming there's a syntax error. I've run the below code successfully using pgAdmin, so I'm not sure why DbUp is having a hard time with it (unless it doesn't support postgres 14?)

Here is my script:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS VARCHAR(11)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    SELECT 'Hello World';
END;
```

and here is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input at character 114
STATEMENT:  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS VARCHAR(11)
 LANGUAGE SQL
 BEGIN ATOMIC
         SELECT 'Hello World'
```

I'm aware I could rewrite the function in plpgsql language, but I want the dependency tracking that SQL language offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ChrisKelly thanks, I wasn't aware of this new syntax! Unfortunately this breaks Npgsql's internal SQL parser, since the semicolon causes the statement to be split... I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4445) to track this as an Npgsql bug; some workarounds are suggested there.

If you can't use the workarounds in that issue, then as I posted previously you can use this alternative syntax, even if it's inferior (dependency tracking and so on):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS VARCHAR(11)
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURN 'Hello World';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Shay! That page mentions that for `sql_body` a block statement using `BEGIN ATOMIC` `END` should still be valid. Trying to execute the code example [at the bottom of this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512) also works in pgAdmin but not in DbUp, giving me the same error as before (syntax error just before the `END`). I have the same issue when trying to create a procedure, too

Comment: @ChrisKelly thanks for raising this, I've learned something... Edited my answer above.

Comment: Unfortunately [DbUp uses named parameters for calling the inserts into its Journal tables](https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp/blob/d2455e93af4e2769154005b74b18993e211484b0/src/dbup-core/Support/TableJournal.cs#L107-L116), [even for Postgres](https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp/blob/d2455e93af4e2769154005b74b18993e211484b0/src/dbup-postgresql/PostgresqlTableJournal.cs#L29), so disabling SqlRewriting is off the table for us. I might open a PR to make those parameters positional for Postgres

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with the new raw SQL mode: there's lots of components out there that already use named parameters on PG.